# Excel counting "A"'s with cell values of "A,B" "R,A" etc

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, countif

Trying to count the number of individual variable in Excel but Countif doesn't seem to fit my needs

For example individual cells have "A","A,B", "A,J", etc and I want to count the number of "A"s - is there a way to do this without entering all the possibilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COUNTIF()` supports wildcards:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:Q2,"*A*")
```

Comment: That returns a zero value for me.  The basic Countif formula I am using is:    =COUNTIF(B2:Q2, "A")

Comment: @TbAd not why that wouldn't work for you, see my edit though.

Answer (score 0):

The custom function below should solve your problem. The above answer only tests to see if an "A" is in the string, not multiple "A"s. eg "AAAA" only returns 1, not 4.

You can see this link for extra details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19481175/general-purpose-udfs-for-using-regular-expressions-in-excel

```
Public Function RXCount(Text As String, Pattern As String, Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = True) As Integer
    Dim retval As Integer
    ' Counts the number of matches
    ' Text is the string to be searched
    ' Pattern is the regex pattern
    ' IgnoreCase (optional) set to False for a case-sensitive search

    Dim RE As Object
    Dim Matches As Object

    Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    RE.IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
    RE.Global = True

    RE.Pattern = Pattern
    Set Matches = RE.Execute(Text)

    retval = Matches.Count

    RXCount = retval
End Function
```